# Problems with smooth scrolling to an anchor

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I am currently developing a site but I am encountering a problem. 
There are several div (item). When I scroll a little bit, the page focuses directly on the whole div (with a height of 100vh). This works perfectly. On the other hand, I tried several methods (js, css, jquery) to do a smooth scroll when you click on a button that points to an anchor, but it doesn't work. After several hours of research I found that the two lines  `overflow: scroll;` and `scroll-behavior: smooth;` are not compatible with each other. When I delete the first one, the automatic focus on the full height of the div no longer works but the smooth scroll of the buttons works correctly, and vice versa. 
Do you know how to "merge" these two effects? 
(I hope you understood my problem, if you have any questions ask me^^)

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" id="accueil">
    <nav> 
      <div class="logo" data-aos="fade-up">
        <img src="elements/illustrations/head.svg" height="100px" width="100px" alt="">
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-links" data-aos="fade-up">
        <li><a class="smoothScroll current" href="#accueil">Accueil</a></li>
        <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#covid19">Covid-19</a></li>
        <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#cyberharcelement">Cyberharcèlement</a></li>
        <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#anticovid">Anti-Covid</a></li>
        <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#galerie">Galerie Saint Germain</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="header">
      <section class="left">
        <div data-aos="fade-up" class="heading">
          <h1>Bonjour &#x1F44B; <br> je m'appelle <span id='jules'>Jules</span>, <br> </h1>
          <div class="typewriter">
            <h1>ravi de vous rencontrer</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="button" class="smoothScroll" data-aos="zoom-in-right" href="#covid19">Découvrir</a>
      </section>

      <section class="right" data-aos="fade-left">
        <div class="illustration">
          <img src="elements/illustrations/illustration.svg" alt="">
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>

    

  </div>
  <div class="item" id="covid19">Covid-19</div>
  <div class="item" id="cyberharcelement">Cyberharcèlement</div>
  <div class="item" id="anticovid">Anti-Covid</div>
  <div class="item" id="galerie">Galerie Saint Germain</div>
</div>
```

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth !important;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  html {
    scroll-behavior: auto;
  }
}

body {
  font-family: var(--inter);
}

.container {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.item {
  color:black;
  /* background: #f5f5f5; */
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

Comment: Why not just do this with scrollIntoView? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. You have to remove `scroll-behavior` from the `HTML` and give **overflow** and **scroll-behavior** to the `container`.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/wk3scpyr/2/

```css
body {
  font-family: var(--inter);
}

.container {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.item {
  color: black;
  /* background: #f5f5f5; */
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item" id="accueil">
      <nav>
        <div class="logo" data-aos="fade-up">
          <img src="elements/illustrations/head.svg" height="100px" width="100px" alt="">
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links" data-aos="fade-up">
          <li><a class="smoothScroll current" href="#accueil">Accueil</a></li>
          <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#covid19">Covid-19</a></li>
          <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#cyberharcelement">Cyberharcèlement</a></li>
          <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#anticovid">Anti-Covid</a></li>
          <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#galerie">Galerie Saint Germain</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <div class="header">
        <section class="left">
          <div data-aos="fade-up" class="heading">
            <h1>Bonjour &#x1F44B; <br> je m'appelle <span id='jules'>Jules</span>, <br> </h1>
            <div class="typewriter">
              <h1>ravi de vous rencontrer</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="button" class="smoothScroll" data-aos="zoom-in-right" href="#covid19">Découvrir</a>
        </section>

        <section class="right" data-aos="fade-left">
          <div class="illustration">
            <img src="elements/illustrations/illustration.svg" alt="">
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>



    </div>
    <div class="item" id="covid19">Covid-19</div>
    <div class="item" id="cyberharcelement">Cyberharcèlement</div>
    <div class="item" id="anticovid">Anti-Covid</div>
    <div class="item" id="galerie">Galerie Saint Germain</div>
  </div>
```